# global action type of lightning component is not visible under link type [tile menu] in lightning community

Tags: salesforce-lightning, lightning

I am trying to add global action type of lightning component in line type [tile menu] in lightning community, but it is not visible. I found that only global action is visible whose record type is accessible to user. But in my case, it is not object specific action. is some other configuration needed to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Hi @Vibhu, I have the same problem : did you find an answer to this issue ?